# How to throw exception/errors from a Modal submit in MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am new to web dev and mvc and I need some help regarding error/exception throw in MVC. 
I have a modal create form with simple submit (no ajax call etc). 
In the create post action in my controller, I checked if the submitted form contains an input that is already in the database. 
As of now, I just redirect to the index of my page if an the submit fails the validation (already existing). 
The result is, my modal create form is closed and had to open the form again with blank values. 
What I want to happen is to just throw a javascript alert about the error, and the modal form and the values would still be there to be edited for another form submit. How can I do this without doing an ajax submit?

Comment: Just add `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.yourProperty)` in the view and then in the POST method, add a `ModelState` error and return the view.

Comment: Post some code, and let us know where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use[unobtrusive validation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/460893/Unobtrusive-AJAX-Form-Validation-in-ASP-NET-MVC)

Dont use RedirectToAction() when model is not valid return the same view using

`return View()`

Comment: Thank you but return View() will not work in my case because the view of my create form, is a partialview modal called inside my index.cshtml. I tried to return PartialView but that partialview relies in the main view. any ideas?